# Google Civic Information API throwing error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-civic-information-api

I'm trying to utilize pygci to pull voting district data for a particular address. I've enabled the Google Civic Information API for the listed key, but all I'm getting is

> "Response was not valid Json"

when I try to run this code:

```
*from pygci import GCivicInfo, GCivicInfoError
API_KEY = 'AIzaSyA1EBhUzaHBaaFB8H7LiWfVQsf0KnuwRSs'
address = "4935 Spruce St. Philadelphia, PA 19139"



CivicInfo = GCivicInfo(api_key=API_KEY)
try:
    CivicInfo.get_representative_by_address(params=address)
except GCivicInfoError as e:
    print(e)*
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the docs for the underlying API](https://developers.google.com/civic-information/docs/v2/representatives/representativeInfoByAddress), it ultimately needs the address to have the keyword "address" encoded as a URL parameter:

```
GET https://civicinfo.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?address=4935%20Spruce%20St.%20Philadelphia%2C%20PA%2019139&key=your_api_key
```

With the `requests` library, you encode parameters into the URL this way by passing it a `dict`. So I was going to suggest you try:

```py
CivicInfo.get_representative_by_address(params={"address": address})
```

But looking at `pygci`, it appears `get_representative_by_address` overwrites `params` with `''`. If you still get an error, there's may be a bug in the library, or I've misunderstood its code.
https://github.com/moosh3/pygci/blob/f80c336a4417f57ce80495e02f0a4a45eb0f4ce1/pygci/endpoints.py#L33

```py
def get_representative_by_address(self, params):
    """Looks up political geography and representative
    information for a single address
    :param address: (optional) type=string
    :param includeOffices: (optional) type=boolean, default=True
    """
    address = ''
    return self.get('/representatives?', params=address)
```

Comment: You could try changing `pygci` so the line is `return self.get('/representatives?', params=params)`. If that doesn't work, try removing the question mark.